# international mathematical competition for college students

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

I randomly came across with the following problems:

Let $A,B \in M_n (\mathbb{C})$ such that $A^2B+B^2A=2ABA.$ Prove that $(AB-BA)^k=0$ for some positive integer $k$. The proof is as follows:

Let $X=AB-BA$, then $A$ commutes with $X$ because $AX-XA=A^2B-2ABA+BA^2=0$. Hence for $m \geq 1$. $X^m=X^{m-1}(AB-BA)=AX^{m-1}B-X^{m-1}BA$. Taking trace gives $tr (X^m)= tr (AX^{m-1}B)-tr (X^{m-1}BA)=0$. Now, $tr X, tr (X^2), ..., tr (X^n)$ uniquely determines the eigenvalues of $X$. Hence $\sigma (X)=0$ , where $\sigma (X)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $X$. Therefore $X$ is nilpotent and we are done.

I tried to make the argument a little bit shorter as follows: We have $tr (X^m)=0$ for all $m \geq 1$, in particular: $tr (X^2)=0$. But we know that $\lambda \in \sigma (X) \Rightarrow \lambda^k \in \sigma (X^k)$. Hence $\sum_{\lambda \in \sigma (X)} \lambda^2=0$. Hence all the eigenvalues of $X$ is zero. But then I realize that the eigenvalue is not necessarily real, so the above argument is wrong. Then I tried to correct it by relpacing the power $2$ by $4$. I want to ask is it feasible?

Comment: No, it is not. Any complex number is a $n$-th power, for every $n$.

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going competition, or a past one?

Comment: The IMC is an on-site competition, so it is certainly not on-going. However, I would appreciate it if the OP could add the year of the competition.

Answer (score 0):

No, you really need $n$ power sums to determine $n$ complex numbers.

This is easier to understand if you convert the power sums to elementary symmetric functions. They are the coefficients of the polynomial that has these $n$ numbers as roots. Since every polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ complex roots and any set of $n$ complex numbers has a unique corresponding (monic) polynomial, you cannot succeed with less information.